# app crashes while clicking an expandable list if any other list is expanded

Tags: android

In my expandable list view, I had opened the list group say, A. while A is open if I click on B, the app will crashes and getting an error as

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
```

code snippet is :

```
expListView.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, long id) {           

        pos = groupPosition;                
        grp = listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);                                
        getlist(grp);                   
        return false;
    }
});
```

getlist() sets the child values for each list.

KIndly help to resolve. appreciating response

Comment: check the line number which makes index out of bound

Comment: post your entire code

Answer (score 0):

Your ArraYlistSize is 0 it means you donot have any thing in your Arraylist and you are trying to access them first fill your array list through this function Arraylist.add(type of your arraylist Item) before this exception Log the size of ArrayList as well Log.d("Array list size is","This"+Arraylist.size());

Comment: its fine and  am getting the arraylist size.
but the exception is still there

Comment: your exception clearly says that you want to access the index of Arraylist 1 but the size of arraylist you have is zero means you have nothing in your Arraylist

Comment: its already added in create like,
    listDataHeader.add(A);, B, C etc

Comment: Then only one things is remains you are clearing your arraylist any where else and when you click you got the null you may be using Arraylist.clear()

Answer (score -1):

I think listDataHeader is empty. Please check. When you are calling below, I think listDataHeader is empty and you are trying to get data from position 1. Whenever you try to access data from a position where the data is not present it throws ArrayIndexOutOfBound exception

```
 grp = listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
```

Comment: its not empty, still it crashes

Comment: Check on which line you are getting crash. Is it at grp = listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);??? Can you post full stack trace

Comment: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 0
java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:147)
android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.expandGroup(ExpandableListConnector.java:685)
android.widget.ExpandableListView.handleItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:691)
android.widget.ExpandableListView.performItemClick(ExpandableListView.java:651)

Comment: Do you see any of your class names in stack trace.. Please post complete stack trace

Comment: class names are not seen

Comment: Not possible. I think the trace you posted is half. If you are on ubuntu you can use below commnad adb logcat | grep "AndroidRuntime"